# How can i make sure using a webBrowser when it's getting to the completed event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using mshtml;

namespace Extract_Images
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] linkstoextract;
        private int numberoflinks;
        private string mainlink;
        private WebClient client;
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;


            label1.Text = "Number of links: ";

            mainlink = "http://www.test.com/index";
            numberoflinks = 211;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberoflinks; i++)
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(mainlink + i + ".html");
                GetHtmlFromUrl(mainlink + i + ".html");
            }

        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        private void GetHtmlFromUrl(string url)
        {

            IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

            foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
            {
                imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

                using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    bmp.Save(@"C:\" + img.nameProp);
                }
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that now i'm using a for loop to loop over each link and extract the images.

The problem is before it will extract all the images from the first link it will keep doing the for loop and already will try to browse to the next link.

I need somehow maybe using a time and while or something else to make sure that it will browse the first link will get to the completed event there it will extract all links of images only when it finished working extracting all images from the first html then keep for the next one in the loop.

Next after i have a List of all images links from all pages then i want to download all the images using the links. But the problem is as i described above.

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of changes to your code, but did so only in a text editor, so I don't have any benefit of compile time checks or logic verification - sorry.  But hopefully my suggested code will help you sort out an approach to get the order-of-operations to behave the way you want.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] linkstoextract;
    private int numberoflinks;
    private int currentLinkNumber = 0;
    private string mainlink;
    private WebClient client;
    private WebBrowser webBrowser1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

        label1.Text = "Number of links: ";

        mainlink = "http://www.test.com/index";
        numberoflinks = 211;

        ProcessNextLink();
    }

    private void ProcessNextLink()
    {
        if (currentLinkNumber < numberoflinks)
        {
            currentLinkNumber++;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(mainlink + currentLinkNumber.ToString() + ".html");
        }   
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessImagesFromDocument();
        ProcessNextLink();
    }

    private void ProcessImagesFromDocument()
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

        foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
        {
            imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

            using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                bmp.Save(@"C:\" + img.nameProp);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

To summarize the suggested changes:

- I created a variable `currentLinkNumber` scoped to the Form that keeps track of the current 'link' that is being processed -- this is serving the same role as  your variable `i` which was scoped only to the `for` loop
- I moved the `Navigate` and incrementing of the variable to its own method, so that we can have a method to call from `DocumentCompleted` after it has completely finished downloading *and* processing the current link
- I renamed your `GetHtmlFromUrl` method to `ProcessImagesFromDocument` because the `url` parameter is not needed at this point, and I also moved the call into `DocumentCompleted`

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that it's never continue after the ProcessImagesFromDocument() method. I used a breakpoint and it's ener get/stop after the foreach. It's just doing nothing the program get to the form i see form1 and that's nothing. Not sure why it's not continue.